# Delayed_Job, How to set a priority for a user_mailer.rb method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job w rails 3 to delay user_mailers, example:

```
 UserMailer.delay.email_digest(from,email,subject,html,text)
```

How can I add a priority? By default all delayed jobs are set to priority 0, for this mailer, I would like to make it less important with a priority of 1.

Possible? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Options such as priority or which queue to use are options on the delay method, for example

```
UserMailer.delay(:priority => 2).email_digest(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even set the queue name so that you can group it according to the task using,

```
UserMailer.delay(:queue=> "Mailers",:priority=>  1).email_digest(from,email,subject,html,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 5**
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def email_digest(email)
    @email = email
    mail(to: @email, subject: 'Hello...')
  end

end
```

`UserMailer.email_digest("email@domain.com").deliver_later(:priority => 75)`

This work for me